# copy specific elements if condition is met

Tags: java, arrays

So basically I have an array with the following sample input:

```
10.2    
20.8    
30.1    
28.7    
43.7    
-10.4    
0.0    
8.0    
30.4    
30.0
```

and I want to copy only elements that are >=30 into another array.

This is the code I currently have, but i'm kind of stuck on how to continue. Any help would be highly appreciated! the double array "reallyWarm" is the array where the copy is being made on

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] temperatures = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    temperatures[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
}
double[] reallyWarm;
```

Comment: If you are just learning loops and arrays, use a first loop to count the numbers of elements > 30. Then create an array with the right length (you just found it). Then use a second loop to copy all elements > 30 to the new array.

Comment: I suggest you use java's collection framework arraylist, as it can grow dynamically.

Comment: I'll make sure to try it, thanks @JBNizet!

Comment: @Programmingboi123 If my solution solved your problem consider it accepting by clicking a left right button , where it will help to other developers in the community

Answer (score 5):

You should use `if (temperatures[i] >= 30.0)` to check for the elements that are greater or equal to `30.0`.

Try this:

```
double[] reallyWarm;
int t = 0;    

for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
    if (temperatures[i] >= 30.0) {
        t++;    // count elements >= 30.0
    }
}
reallyWarm = new double[t];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
    if (temperatures[i] >= 30.0) { 
        reallyWarm[j] = temperatures[i];    
        j++;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reallyWarm));
```

If you're using java 8 you can achive this task with just one line of code:

```
double[] reallyWarm;
reallyWarm = Arrays.stream(temperatures).filter(e -> e >= 30.0).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reallyWarm));
```

Output:

```
[30.1, 43.7, 30.4, 30.0]
```

Update for '... a new line after each element...':

```
for(int i=0; i<reallyWarm.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(reallyWarm[i]);
}
```

You can use a for loop to traverse through the array and print each element on a new line.

Comment: it's good, but i really want a new line after each element instead.

Comment: you can use a for loop to traverse through the array and print each element on a new line. updating the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Using Java8 Stream :

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    Double arr[] = { 10.2, 20.8, 30.1, -10.4, 30.4, 0.0, 30.0, 43.7 };
    List<Double> result = Arrays.asList(arr).stream().filter(k -> k >= 30).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JAVA 8 and higher version:

```
double temperatures[] = { 10.2, 20.8, 30.1, -10.4, 30.4, 0.0, 30.0, 43.7 };
double reallyWarm[] = Arrays.stream(temperatures).filter(d -> d >= 30).toArray();
```